# High-quality open-source text-to-speech (TTS) engines written in Java

Tags: java, text-to-speech

I'm looking for open-source text-to-speech (TTS) engines written **purely** in Java. That is no native calls or similar — pure Java only. Ideally with high-quality voices (see quality definition below), but also lower quality alternatives are okay as long as the source is available.

Does such an open source project exist?

By "high-quality" I mean "human sounding", "non-robotic" and with end results roughly on par with these two English language examples: [Example 1](http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=en&q=This+is+an+example+to+illustrate+the+desired+level+of+quality), [Example 2](http://tts-api.com/tts.mp3?q=This+is+an+example+to+illustrate+the+desired+level+of+quality)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only open source java TTS engine I am aware of is [MARY](http://mary.dfki.de/) which came out of research labs and universities. It has not been active for a while and I have not heard the quality of the output.

Comment: Actually, and depending on your language, it's the best quality opensource TTS engine right now. It's actively developed.